# Reputation on edit

Tags: support, stack-overflow, reputation

For the last 2 days, since there've been upgrade of server, I've noticed that **NO reputation** is being attributed for edits. Is it a bug? 
And I don't know if there's a place where I can review if my edits has been accepted or rejected. But seem to me that there is a problem with reputation attribution.
Can someone confirm this please?

Comment: You've reached 2000 reputation; you don't gain reputation points for edits any longer.

Comment: Ah ok.. So upon reaching 2000 rep, no rep is attributed? Now I understand ;) thnx

Comment: @Nadeem upon reaching 2000 rep your edits are instant and do not go through any review process. The +2 is gained only after reviewer approve a suggested edit.